# ipad font size different than android tablet

Tags: android, css, html, ipad, fonts

Something strange it happens in my website.

When i see the site from and ipad the font gets bigger than the font that shows the android tablet.

Is there something i'm missing here.

I see in this post https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/how-to/2010/12/save-your-layout-by-overriding-the-minimum-font-size-on-the-iphone-and/ i need to change this css property, any thoughts about this:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Currently my site have this propertie with different value:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

Comment: please also provide a link to the actual site, otherwise you're just asking people to guess.

Comment: Sorry this is the site address: http://209.208.111.220:8080/dealer-web

Comment: please put that in your post, not as a comment.